# CakePHP 3.2 changing default order of date form input

Tags: forms, date, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to get cakephp to generate the following HTML `<div class="input date"><label>Leverdatum </label><select name="Leverdatum [day]">...</select><select name="Leverdatum [month]">...</select><select name="Leverdatum [year]">...</select></div>` so that the order of inputting the date is day-month-year.
However cake is generating it in the order of year-day-month.
The code I'm using on my .ctp page is `echo $this->Form->input('Leverdatum ', ['type' => 'date', 'default' => date("d-m-y", strtotime($orders->DELIVERYDATE))]);` but this only fills in the correct date and doesn't order the select boxes the way I want them to.
I have found that in previous versions of cakePHP you could use `'dateFormat' => 'DMY'` to achieve this. But this has apperantly been removed from cakePHP. 

Now I did find a 'fix' which is to edit the cakePHP files at \Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper in `protected $_defaultConfig` change the variable `'dateWidget' => '{{year}}{{month}}{{day}}{{hour}}{{minute}}{{second}}{{meridian}}'` to the order I want it in `'dateWidget' => '{{day}}{{month}}{{year}}{{hour}}{{minute}}{{second}}{{meridian}}'`. But I don't really want to have to do this every time I want to update my cakePHP version.

My question is: Is there a way to tell cake what order I want my date to be in, aside from editting their source files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all explained in the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)

Anyway instead of editing the `$_defaultConfig` create a file in your config folder an name it something like `my_form_templates.php`

and in it write your templates

```
<?php
    return [
        'dateWidget' => '{{day}}{{month}}{{year}}{{hour}}{{minute}}{{second}}{{meridian}}'
    ];
?>
```

then when you load FormHelper you can do

```
 $this->loadHelper('Form', [
        'templates' => 'my_form_templates',
    ]);
```

this tells cake to use your templates instead of the default ones